# aspnet core mvc, how to preview any type of file in html?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net-core, model-view-controller

I am using aspnet core mvc dotnet version 6.

I do an file upload page. In this page, I must show files before upload. I can preview pdfs and text files in iframe. But I want also preview docx or excell files. How can i do that?

Here is my js method:

```
function PreviewFiles() {
        console.log("Dosyalar yükleniyor...");
        console.log("Dosyalar ön izlemeye alınıyor...");

        var files = document.getElementById("FilesToUpload").files;
        console.log(files);
        var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        $("#FilePreviewFrame").attr('src', fileUrl);
        $("#FilePreviewFrame").attr('height', "500");
        formData = new FormData();
        console.log("Dosyalar formdata elemanına kaydediliyor...");

        for (var i = 0; i !== files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("files", files[i]);
        }

    }
```

***Note: Like i said, i can preview pdf and text files. I need to preview ms office documents.***

Comment: You need something that knows how to do that. Likely you will want a third party library that can render office documents on a web page.

Comment: Yes I do, there is a bad solution like: If I open an office program on server, I can take all page and convert to picture. But this solution is worth. 
So if a 3rth party lib can do that, I can use it.

Comment: [open xml power tools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) might be an option for you to get html from a document. I googled it, I can't answer any questions about it.